# PyCharm terminal autocompletion prints ^[^G

Tags: linux, terminal, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm 2017.2.
When I open terminal tab and try to use autompletion, for example:
Type: `python ma + Tab_key` and I want to get string `python manage.py`.
But result is `python ^[^Gmanage.py`.
The same with `cd` and the other shell commands.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the shell's prompt **`PS1`** string has embedded escape sequences to change the window title.  Those would begin with **`^[`** (escape) and could end with **`^G`** (see the [xterm FAQ](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#what_is_vt220) for some background).